# boost geometry angle between two points

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I'm playing with boost geometry (1.74) and there are a lot of examples using the `distance` algorithm which is great.  How ever I'm struggling to find an example for calculating the angle (bearing) between two points.

It looks like the atan2 function is used inside details/azimuth.hpp but is not exposed on the API as at the same level the distance algorithm is.

So my question is, how does one use boost geometry to calculate the angle between two points?

Thanks in advance.

Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite right about the `atan2` function in `details/azimuth.hpp`.
The angle (bearing) between two points is often called the azimuth.

It is defined in the file: `<boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/azimuth.hpp>` that you refer to, but unfortunately it is not listed in the documentation for [boost algorithms](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms.html).

You should be able to call it like `distance` here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/quickstart.html

However, because it's defined in the `detail` namespace you may have to *use* the `boost::geometry::detail` namespace or call it explicitly, e.g.:

```
auto bearing = boost::geometry::detail::azimuth<double>(a, b);
```

Comment: I would hesitate to advertise undocumented implementation details (not part of public API) as they can have equally undocumented limitations/pre-/post conditions and will not have to be kept stable over versions. +1 nonetheless

Comment: @sehe you raise a very good point about the status of the `azimuth` algorithm. I've just raised the following issue: https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/issues/771 about it. Thanks for the up vote.

Answer (score 1):

Boost v1.76 now exposes Azimuth.  Thanks all!